# Nearest Toeplitz matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, toeplitz-matrices

Consider I have an arbitrary $n \times n$ Hermitian matrix $A$. I want to derive a "suitable" Toeplitz matrix from $A$. I understand that there may be several ways to get a Toeplitz matrix from $A$ so question may be not clear under this broad term. Is this a problem well defined and there are papers related to it?

I am interested to find the Toeplitz matrix with minimal change in the eigenvectors. Specifically I want find the Toeplitz matrix such that its $L_2$ norm between the eigenvectors of the Toeplitz matrix and eigenvectors of the matrix $A$ is minimal. Can anyone help me how to go about it?

Comment: What you perhaps should search for is literature on _perturbations_ of Toeplitz matrices, which have definitely been studied. I recall that it's covered in some of the works of Bottcher, so you may want to check those out in particular. Also, the case of low-rank perturbations of tridiagonal Toeplitz matrices is surveyed in this reference: http://www.math.kent.edu/~reichel/publications/toep3.pdf

Comment: Are you still interested in this question?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Yes, I would like to know an answer to this question. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: Does [this](https://mathoverflow.net/a/295232/91764) help?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a full answer to your question, but all toeplitz matrices can be decomposed into the product of a Vandermonde matrix and a diagonal matrix. In this way, your question is about finding the Vandermonde matrix with the smallest principal angle between subspaces to to the eigenvector matrix in question